# Two-way interaction term and simple slope

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

In my study, I am looking at `gender` interaction with an independent variable. In the fitted linear regression, if the `gender*var1` coefficient is non-significant, but the simple slope for `gender=female` is positive and significant (non-significant simple slope for `gender=male`), can one still make conclusion about females?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you first fitted a regression model with an interaction term between gender and `var1`. In this model, the estimated coefficient was not significantly different than zero.

Then you fitted two separate regression models, one for females and one for males. In the model for females, the estimated regression coefficient (slope) for `var1` is statistically significantly different from zero, whereas, in the model for males, the same estimated coefficient is not significant.

And your question is whether based on the results of these separate models you could still conclude that there is an interaction between `var1` and gender? If yes, then the answer is no, because even if one estimated coefficient is different than zero and the other is not, this doesn't mean that the *difference* between the coefficients, which is what you want to test and what the interaction term is actually doing, is statistically different from zero.

Comment: Thank you @dimitris-rizopoulos. You are right about how I went about it. My question however is not to make conclusion about the interaction, but about the relationship between `var1` and `outcome` for females. Assuming the coefficient of `var1` for females is positive and significant and for males is nonsignficant, could I make a statement that `var1` has a positive effect for females, but no effect for males? Is this fine despite the fact that coefficient of `gender*var1` was insignificant?

Comment: Yes, you could say that the coefficient of `var1` is different from 0 for females, but you cannot say that there is a difference with males.

Comment: Thank you. This leaves me confusing. I understand that I cannot conclude that there is a gender difference because interaction coefficient is nonsignificant. But by saying that for females the slope is different from zero, but for males it is not, am I not saying the same thing that there is gender difference?